Module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool8' In cartpole problem openai gym
I'm beginner & trying to run this simple code but it is giving me this exception "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool8'" as you can see in screenshot below. Gym version is 0.26.2 & numpy version is 2.1.1. I've tried downgrading both but visual studio won't let me do that. I have installed latest verison of everything and I know this is happening because the newer version doesn't allow the use of bool8 instead using bool_ will help but i don't know where should i change bool8 to bool_ i can't see this in my code. How can i make it work?

import gym

# Create the CartPole environment
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')

# Reset the environment to start
state = env.reset()

# Run for 1000 timesteps
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()  # Render the environment
    action = env.action_space.sample()  # Take a random action
    state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)  # Step the environment by one timestep

    # If the episode is done (CartPole has fallen), reset the environment
    if done:
        state = env.reset()

env.close()  # Close the rendering window

On clicking show call stack it shows this :-


I don't know Visual Studio well but I guess "Show Call Stack" will show you which function in which module tried to use bool8.

it only shows main : 13, which is the same line i'm getting error on

That's known issue. You can try to downgrade numpy to 1.23.5 because from 1.24 bool8 is deprecated:
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.23.5


so there is not way to make it work with the latest version, by changing code or something? i have to work on depreciated library?

@Jitender - The easiest solution is: yes, work with the old one. However, you always can try to dig into that gym's source code and try to change it manually too. If you 100% sure what you do,
